# Проблемы с нейронной сетью, запущенной через crontab

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow, crontab

При ручном запуске скрипта нейронной сети (для классификации текстов) классификация проходит как нужно, но почему-то при запуске скрипта через crontab сеть выдаёт абсолютно другие результаты. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой? Как можно её исправить?

**Пример проблемы:**

При ручном  запуске сеть определяет что тестовый текст относится к первой категории, что правильно, но при запуске скрипта через crontab сеть выдаёт абсолютно другой результат, относя его почему-то к 8 категории, учитывая что она обучалась только на 6 категориях.

Comment: Пример строки из крона? Пользуетесь виртуальными окружениями? anaconda, может быть?

Comment: Сравните окружения при запуске ручном запуске и при запуске из под crontab.